# How many stages would it take for a character to be convinced of x?

Tags: characters, plot

My MC - who has a dangerous reputation - is captured by a member of Bolivian Security, who decides to take him to her father in-law (who also has a dangerous reputation)to be questioned instead of going straight to HQ.

Said father in-law is a semi retired master of manipulation and torturer extraordinaire. She only knows from his stories that he always got to the truth.

He takes the prisoner, she starts to tell him what she wants but he shuts her down - never in front of the prisoner - it pollutes the process. He  just gets started and then goes to her to learn what intel she needs to confirm. When he learns that she wants to know if the prisoner can be trusted he finds himself in a bit of a bind.

He is shifting him from torture victim to houseguest but finding a considerable cynicism regarding this apparent change. He has never had occasion to even attempt to essentially befriend someone he started working on - unique situation.

I am not asking what to write - I am in the process of writing it. I am only wondering at what point would it be reasonable for said character to wonder if this might be a genuine approach and not something from chapter three, subsection 12 of Advanced Technique and Methodology: A Handbook.

This is a clash of two dark reputations, both are aware of the other and that is the difficulty in that the MC knows he cannot believe one word.

Edit:
He will never believe the father in-law, but how many stages should it realistically take for him to go from ‘not killing me’ to ‘I will help her’?

Comment: "the MC knows he cannot believe one word." <–– I think that's your answer.

Comment: Probably. For the past six pages the torturer has been treating my MC like a four year old colt just brought in from the field to be reacquainted with humans and taught to be a saddle horse after learning what it is to be a horse. He even ascribes some equine tells to my MC to help him read him and guide him in this constructive process. Of course, horses are conditioned to trust humans unless the covenant is broken and my MC does not trust this man.

Comment: Just thought I'd say, I VTCed not for "what to write", I don't think it is that, but as "opinion-based".

Comment: @Galastel I appreciate you mentioning that. Sometimes it seems the paradox of this subject as the subjective nature of writing lends to opinions. There are so few situations where there can be but one correct answer and all others are wrong. Often, there are ten correct answers and each differs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To recap the question: **"What steps to get an MC to accept a villain is now helping, when he knows the villain was planning to kill him before?"**

### Your MC would have dealt with sudden alliance shifts before.

This situation is not unfamiliar to your MC. He's going to be adaptable, and be able to separate his own feelings from the job. He will be able to work with someone who he knows is a killer, after all it is his own profession. Nothing personal.

I have some problems with this torturer character. It feels contrived that he insists on "prepping for surgery" before he is able to hear a simple comment like "I just want to know if I can trust him?" It's like one of those eyerolling sitcom misunderstandings where the whole episode could have been cleared up just by stating the goal at the beginning.

### I'd keep the idea of frenemy-whiplash, but tweak the focus.

Ms Bolivia has a captured agent (MC) and can't go back to HQ. She and MC have an exchange where she *needs* to trust MC because she can't trust her own. She can't even go to a safe house because they are known to her agency. Her options are to connect MC with his own forces (which she's not about to do), or take a risk of bringing MC with her to (her?) mysterious father-in-law who has the scary reputation and whom the Bolivian Security Forces have disavowed – whatever she suspects about her own team, could be confirmed or elaborated on by Torturer because his ties to the ultra-secret chambers of power run deep (also why he continues to live at his compound unbothered by the Bolivian government).

MC will do a few things to show Ms Bolivia that they are allies now, at least while they have a common enemy. MC cooperates, there is a skirmish where they back each other up to get away, etc. She doesn't trust him, but as an outsider he is definitely not the mole. She needs to know something about her own forces without going through her own forces – that means finding scary torturer – not because he can say if MC is trustworthy, but because **he would know the truth about her own agency at the highest levels** (insert earlier evidence showing a schism between Torturer and whomever is potentially corrupted. What made the Torturer "bad" before, now makes him a potential ally against her corrupt agecy).

MC knows her situation is unstable, survival depends on *unknowns* like how independent she is, and how willing she is to accept that her own agency is against her. She will resist going rogue out of loyalty. MC may need to talk her out of calling agents she trusts. He's got to make her see the reality of the situation **and** get her to trust him, but of course as a captured enemy agent he would say things to get her not to report him.... All the attention is put on this tenuous trust between these two. Basically Ms Bolivia is a target to her own forces and suddenly her only friend is a man she was sent out to arrest/kill. She's out on a limb. Maybe together they realize there's one person who would know the truth, but it's a man neither would choose to trust.

MC and Ms Bolivia enter Torturer's compound, are overwhelmed by Torturer's guards, separated, and MC ends up in a cell. You can have the overtures to torture but it's not because the father-in-law is too compulsive, it's a reasonable reaction after his compound was invaded by agents who shouldn't be working together. Also, where are the other agents…? It's very interesting to Torturer, and if there are any questions/threats it's mostly about why MC is working with Bolivian forces. It's presumed Ms Bolivia is going through the same experience, and it's [the Prisoner's Dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoner's_dilemma). Each could easily implicate the other, but telling the truth only works if Ms Bolivia is *also* sticking with the truth. MC's question of trust is still Ms Bolivia.

MC is released, maybe the cell just opens or he discovers a lapse in the guards and believes he is escaping. He stays hidden, making his way deeper into the compound only to discover Ms Bolivia and Creepy Torturer are sitting on the veranda drinking tea. They are expecting him and seem awfully cozy. Torturer is relaxed and playing the gracious host, in fact he's amused by Ms Bolivia's story, she is just confirming something he knew all along. (This also might be the time to reveal Torturer is her(?) father-in-law.) MC has a shock that he was acting in good faith while in the cell trying to protect them both, and here she is relaxing and looking fine. Again the lingering distrust and sudden reversal is focused between MC and Ms Bolivia – something Torturer might pick up on and also find amusing.

From there your story goes ahead as planned, but you have 3 frenemies agreeing to cooperate, none of which will be longterm allies even under the best of circumstances. MC will still be a professional, but once the corruption thing is solved MC is right back where he started, either in a frying pan or in a fire. Depending on who comes out on top.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. What I have at the moment is Ms Bolivia calling her husband from the van - asking to meet at his father’s place. She needs a huge favour etc. Needs someone questioned. Son tells his father who has certain expectations. He is semi retired and believed dead by most - including the MC. MC realizes where he is being taken and that his chances of survival have plummeted from 60% to 4% and he must do something. The van door opens, he makes an unsuccessful bolt for it and is shot with a paralytic by the torturer. That is when she tries to tell him what she wants

Comment: He tells her to go inside with her daughter and proceeds to get acquainted with the MC, who knows this is it.

Comment: So it boils down to remain respected adversaries and never really worry about long term trust. It might evolve naturally, though is unnecessary. MC is currently trying to improve his situation, though doubts he will leave alive as long as this torturer is in the picture.

Comment: He would probably have a healthy mistrust of everyone, considering it is a world of assassins and political intrigue…. I think you have suspension of disbelief working in your action-universe which I would not accept, but I saw part of a Bond movie last night and couldn't believe that either (torture is 100% reliable; from no-win scenario to all enemies shot dead 10sec later), so I don't think I'm the audience for "assassin heroes", even high-budget and polished none of those characters made sense and scenes happened just so the villain could escape or Bond could look cool.... It's the genre.

Comment: perhaps it is the genre, but I am trying to minimize or eliminate the completely unbelievable characters.

Comment: My character is wary of others in his world though I could make that stronger.

Answer (score 3):

I would propose that a person's resistance to a potential threat will generally decrease over time, as long as no new signs of threat are introduced.  The precise rate of decrease is a story question.

However, how quickly you are willing to trust likely has a second factor - which is what other threats are perceived.  Thus, it may take awhile for your character to fully trust there is no trick when nothing else is going on, but if the general background threat level is high, "you haven't actively tried to kill or maim me in the last hour, so what the heck" will start to kick in.

That is, it could take months for your character to trust if he's not let go, but otherwise not threatened.  It could be a matter of minutes if a mutual threat is overrunning the compound.  Perception of Immediate Threat below generic fear levels will not trigger significant caution.

[image: Perception of Immediate Threat below generic fear levels will not trigger significant caution]

Separately, threat assessment will be based on how well the character can justify threatening / non-threatening motive attribution.  Being allowed to leave if he wants, or being left alone with the torturer's beloved daughter, would be hard to reconcile with "it's all a ruse." (But what if he doubts that she's really the daughter!)

Being kept under close scrutiny and limited in his access would not offer such counterfactuals.

Answer (score 3):

#### Reality

People are different. Some will be afraid to be killed for the rest of their lives. This is called [PTSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posttraumatic_stress_disorder) and common in torture victims. [Others will never feel in danger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M._(patient)) even when under the knife. Everything in between is realistically possible.

#### Fiction

You can write your character however you like.

If you prepare the reader by setting the character up well, any behavior will be believable.